# String replace in Spark RDD

Tags: python, pyspark

I will explain the problem first mentioning the code.

```
numPartitions = 2
rawData1 = sc.textFile('train_new.csv', numPartitions,use_unicode=False)


rawData1.take(1)

['1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,0,9,0,0,0,0,0,Class_2']
```

Now i want to replace  **Class_2**   to `2`

after replacement answer should be

```
['1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,0,9,0,0,0,0,0,2']
```

Once i get it for this row, i will perform the operation for the whole data set

Thanks in Advance
Aashish

Answer (score 0):

```
result = rawData1.map(lambda element: ','.join(element.split(',')[:-1] + ['2']))
```

should more than do it. It works by mapping each element in your RDD to the `lambda` function, and returns a new dataset.

The element is split into an array using the ',' delimiter, sliced through to omit the last element, and then made to take an extra element `['2']`, following which we join the array together using ','.

More elaborate constructions can be made by modifying the lambda function appropriately.